# algebraic word problem involving algebraic manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My weekly pay is increased by $200 per week.

Half of my pay now goes to pay the rent and $100 to buy groceries.

If this leaves me with $450, what is my original weekly pay?

My attempt:

$1/2(x+200)-100=450$

$1/2(x+200)=550$

$(x+200)=275$

$x=75$

The textbook answer is $900

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you accidentally divided 550 in half instead of doubling it. That should fix your problem, because 2(550)=1100 and 1100-200 is 900

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You made a small calculation mistake

$1/2(x+200)=550$

It should be $(x+200)=1100$ but not $(x+200)=275$

$\dfrac12(x+200)=550$

Then $x+200=1100$

$x=900$